# How to Get single character before and after of a string?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string :

String 1 :

> this is test12-23.

String 2 :

> This is test12-33-99.

String 1 output :

> 12 => t,- and 23 => -,. can be array no issue, I just need this

String 2 output :

> 12 => t,- and 33 => -,- and 99 => -,.

Question is: **I want to get the before and after letter/character of every integers.**

I know this is possible by regex, but I am not able to make this possible. Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is `t,-`? do you need only the numbers?

Comment: before and after of 12. and -, . before and after of integer 23
 I need before and after letter. Its very specific requirement.

Comment: try regex [\d]+ and check

Comment: @KD : I don't need integers, I need before and after letters of every integers inside the string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`RegExp#exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) method with [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html) regex. Although you need to use [lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for getting following character otherwise regex will exclude the following character from the next match.

```js
var str = ' test12-23. test12-33-99. ';
var regex = /(.)(\d+)(?=(.))/g, m;

while (m = regex.exec(str)) {
  console.log(m[2] + ' => ' + m[1] + ' , ' + m[3])
}
```

Comment: I need 12 => t,- ** 23  => -,. ** 12 => t,- ** 33 => -, - ** 99 => -,. 
Your code is not generating that. Its something weird its showing output.